# Pegar data hora dispositivo phonegap

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Como eu faço para pegar a data hora do dispositivo usando o phonegap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que uma possível solução seria a seguinte:

```
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Com certeza ajudou! muito obrigado.